# rename tablenames of asp.net administration tool's website

Tags: asp.net-membership

i have rename the table name of asp.net administration tool's website now its not working when i click on security it gives an error(invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permissions) so please let me know if any one have solution.

Answer (score 1):

un-rename the table name?